# Grails 3.0.0 findOrCreateBy() missing

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Unless I've missed something it seems that the findOrCreateBy() dynamic methods are now missing in 3.0. Is this intentional?

Thanks

Comment: It still shows as being in the documentation: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrCreateBy.html

Comment: It's also present in the source code on GitHub: https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/finders/FindOrCreateByFinder.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be missing something. It's still there, both in the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrCreateBy.html) and in the [source code](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/finders/FindOrCreateByFinder.java) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I was getting missing method errors even after a grails clean but I trashed the target dir and it seems to be working now